# Chrome Extension: Injecting Javascript showing code rather than output

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a problem with my Javascript code. My intentions are to have text at the top of a page, but instead of showing text I get the actual code instead of 'Hello World':

Image of my error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot65M.png

Here is my manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"],
  "js": ["contentscript.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}
],
"web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"]
```

and here is my contentscripts.js:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.style.width = "100%";
iframe.style.height = "50px";
iframe.style.border = "0px";
iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL("script.js");
document.body.insertBefore(iframe, document.body.firstChild);
```

script.js is simply:

```
document.write("Hello World!");
```

Comment: Makes sense, you're essentially creating `<iframe src="script.js"></iframe>` which should display the contents of script.js

Comment: @PaulS. Despite *normally* being bad practice, in this case they're `document.write`ing to the document of an *iframe*, not the parent page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED: This works for me:

In manifest.json: (I had SSL issues so changed the google "matches" from https to http.)

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "testing document write",
    "description": "testing document write from separate file",
    "version": "1.0",

    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://google.com/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["scriptjs.html"]
}
```

In contentscripts.js:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.style.width = "100%";
iframe.style.height = "50px";
iframe.style.border = "0px";

iframe.src = 'http://fully-qualified-URL/scriptjs.html'; // <-- LOAD HTML

document.body.insertBefore(iframe, document.body.firstChild);
```

And in scriptjs.html:

```
<script>
    document.write('Hello World');
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. All I get when I load it into Chrome is white space. No text appears.

Comment: I set up the code I shared as as Chrome Extension and found that the iframe.src in the contentscripts.js needed to be a fully qualified URL (http://fully-qualified-URL/scriptjs.html). However the manifest.json has only the filename (scriptjs.html). I updated the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Your script still needs to be wrapped in a `<script>` element.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = chrome.extension.getURL("script.js");

// Have to insert the iframe before `contentWindow` is available.
document.body.insertBefore(iframe, document.body.firstChild);
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);
```